# including the OracleClient dll file with release version

Tags: c#, oracle

I had made small c# program that use oracle database so I had to include 
reference

> Data.OracleClient

after releasing my project and move it to the working environment I got problem 
which is missing the reference Data.OracleClient

why the Data.OracleClient won't be included within the release version of my project ?????

what should I have to do to force the including of that library which is necessary to let my project work sinces i am not able to copy the dll file to all PSs on my network ??

and if i used the

> Oracle.DataAccess.Client

how i know the equivalent keyworks with this library ??

should I rebuild the whole project ?!

Answer (score 0):

`Data.OracleClient` is a Microsoft DLL which is usually installed on each Windows PC, i.e. :NET Framework. However, it has been [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for many years and should not be used for new projects.

You may supply `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` with you application, however the Oracle Client must be installed on the target machine.

As an alternative consider to use the ODP.NET Managed Driver, you can download it from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

In this case you have to supply only single DLL `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll`